# SysTick interrupt doesnt trigger (Arm Cortex M0)

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, cortex-m, texas-instruments

I'm using a PGA970 with a ARM Cortex M0 and I'm struggling with the basic function of its SysTick interrupt. Neither Texas Instruments nor Arm could help me as they each ask me to consult the other.
My current state is this:

```c
void main(void) {  
  Interrupt_Config();
  __set_PRIMASK(0);                     //Enables Interrupts
  SYST_Config(0x0000004F,0x00000007);   //configures Reload value + enables counting
  while(1) {}                             //stay in main and wait for Interrupt
}
```

with this definition:

```
void Interrupt_Config(void)
{
   /* Clear interrupt pending register */
   NVIC_UNPEND0 = 0xFFFFFFFF;

   /* Set priority of NVIC interrupt */
   NVIC_PRI0 = 0x80400000;
   NVIC_PRI1 = 0xC0C0C0C0;

   /*
    * Enable NVIC interrupts
    * NVIC interrupt for external interrupt 1 i.e. TADC is disabled
    */
   NVIC_ENABLE0 = 0xFFFFFFFD;
}
```

According to Ti priority of SysTick is set to -1 with the highest priority being -3 (used by fault handlers). Custom interrupts start with the priority of 1.

SysTick M0 System Timer SysTick Registers:

- SYST_CSR  0x00000007  SysTick Control and Status Register [Memory Mapped]
- SYST_RVR  0x0000004F  SysTick Reload Value Register [Memory Mapped]
- SYST_CVR  0x00000000  SysTick Current Value Register [Memory Mapped]

These are my SysTick registers. The CSR register is enabled by setting the value of 7. When the Current Value Register hits 0 it gets reset to the Reload Value which is defined in the RVR. When this reload happens the Countflag-Bit in the CSR is set to 1. Everything of this is working as described in my case.

After the Countflag-Bit is set, an interrupt should be triggered executing the Syst_Handler as shown below. Since I'm using it as a basic counter for now I can confirm that it never gets called.

```
int SYSTcounter=0;
interrupt void SYST_Handler(void) {  
  SYSTcounter++;
}
```

Now to the weird part. The NVIC_INT_CTRL register was renamed by Ti and represents the ISCR of ARM. After executing the Code and waiting for the Countflag it has a Value of 0x67108867. The SysTick exception has a value of 15 --> 1111 which can be seen in VECACTIVE in the picture below. BUT the VECPENDING remains empty same for ISRPENDING.
[ISCR values and explanation of Bits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6ErK.png)

As far as my understanding goes something most probably some stupid setting I forgot prevents my Systick from being executed although it realises that it should be executed. My interrupts in general are working as an unexpected power loss triggers the FaultHandler on the next startup as desired.

Responsible for that should be this code in my startup.c file but to be honest I don't really know what it's doing. Also SYST_TESTING is set to 1.

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION(g_pfnVectors, ".intvecs")
void (* const g_pfnVectors[])(void) =
{
   (void (*)(void))((unsigned long)&__STACK_TOP),
                                            // The initial stack pointer
   ResetISR,                                // The reset handler
   NmiSR,                                   // The NMI handler
   FaultISR,                                // The hard fault handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                       // The MPU fault handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                       // The bus fault handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                       // The usage fault handler
   0,                                       // Reserved
   0,                                       // Reserved
   0,                                       // Reserved
   0,                                       // Reserved
   IntDefaultHandler,                       // SVCall handler
   IntDefaultHandler,                       // Debug monitor handler
   0,                                       // Reserved
   IntDefaultHandler,                       // The PendSV handler
#if (SYST_TESTING == 1)
   SYST_Handler,                           // The M0 System timer handler
#else
   IntDefaultHandler,                      // The M0 System timer handler
#endif
   ADC_Handler,  // ADC handler
   IntDefaultHandler,
#if(OWI_TESTING == 1) //
   OWI_Activation_Handler, // OWI_Activation_Handler, OWI Activation handler
#else
   IntDefaultHandler,
#endif
#if (COMBUF_TESTING == 1)
   COMBUF_Handler,                          // COMBUF RX handler
#else
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
#endif
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
   IntDefaultHandler,                       //
};
```

Anybody got any Ideas?

Comment: All the magic numbers in your code are impossible to review and see what is wrong.  Just use the standard library functions provided by CMSIS.  They work and do exactly what you want.

Comment: Writing hex constants like you do is dangerous. Their type depends on their value, not how many zero digits you type in front of them. For example, on a 16 bit computer `0x0000004F` is type `int`, `0x0000804F` is type `unsigned int`, `0x7000004F` is type `signed long` and `0x8000004F` is type `unsigned long`. Start by always using `u` suffix behind every single hex constant in your code. Then get rid of the dangerous practice of writing 0x0000... in front.

Comment: (TI tech support no matter what you ask is completely useless. You should never design in any TI components for that reason - they have no support.)

Comment: Anyway, are you sure that `SYST_Handler` isn't called? What does the disassembly look like, is the ISR there? Does it contain any code? Missing volatile on `int SYSTcounter=0;` could be causing strange optimizer bugs particularly on old compilers.

Comment: I don't know this hardware, but shouldn't SYST_Handler be loaded into a vector table somewhere?

Comment: @Tom Sadly the standard library functions of CMSIS don't seem to work since Ti either didnt include the needed header files which i cant find anywhere or they aren't supported for my  Device. For example searching for "void __enable_irq(void)         // Enable Interrupts" as described simply doesn't find any results.

Comment: @Lundin Most of the values which were set this way have a determined type, as for example the function void SYST_Config(UL reloadCnt, UL systControl). So I think that shouldnt be a problem for me in this case but thanks for the advice! 
Yes im pretty sure that the SYST_Handker() isn't executed since I use step by step debugging. Aditionally my IDE shows each function that gets executed. The ISR contain only one function which is the Interrupt_Config I showed in my post.

Comment: Please post your vector table.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes you're right. I added another source code snippet from the project at the bottom of my original post. Although I have no real clue what it's doing it could be what you were talking of.

Comment: It looks ok. The Systick should be at position 16 (index 15 in C). Also your Systick registers looks correctly set. Just to verify, you could temporarily add an `#ifdef SYST_TESTING #error ok it is defined #endif` to the same file and compile. (Or read the preprocessor output)

Comment: @Lundin I've got a switch.h file managing the inclusion of header files. 
`#define ON  1
#define OFF 0
#define SYST_TESTING            ON`
I can't directly read its value but I would recieve an error if it wouldnt be set to 1.

Comment: That won't do any good if that header is somehow not visible to the vector table file. Same thing if the function prototype of `SYST_Handler` isn't visible to the vector table.

Comment: That is, some "weak" default definition of `SYST_Handler` might be present and linked if it can't find your version of it. You could easily test this by renaming your function to `x` and then mod the vector table replacing `SYST_Handler` with `x` there as well. If it doesn't link, well then that's the problem.

Comment: @Lundin I renamed the function as you suggested but it still seems to link, so it should be fine i guess.

Comment: Then I think we've ruled out a lot of the possible problems. I guess it is something with NVIC interrupt enable not correctly set up then. This assuming `__set_PRIMASK(0); ` actually enables global interrupts - it should boil down to `CPSIE i` and not `CPSID i`, check the disassembly.

Comment: I've read some posts about `CPSIE i` and `CPSID i` before but the given ARM configurations didn't work for them. I'm new to coding and still learning, what excatly do you mean with the disassembly and how should I check it?

Comment: These two instructions enable or disable the global interrupt mask. Every MCU no matter flavour typically got a status or "condition code" register enabling or disabling all interrupts on the MCU. This flag gets automatically set by the core whenever you enter an ISR and then gets cleared when you return. You also need to do the `CPSIE` manually once, when all setups/initialization is done and you want to launch interrupts.

Comment: By disassemble I mean view the generated machine code assembler generated by the compiler. Good IDEs provide a separate disassembler, but in case it doesn't you can usually view it in your debugger when you download the program. It needs to say `CPSIE` somewhere in your code. However if you got other interrupts working, then this isn't the problem.

Comment: @Lundin Well in my previous code which had actual purposes at least the IntDefaultHandler got called once I cut off the power supply, turned it on again and reconnected to the Board. But that doesnt seem to be the case with my testcode...
For the disassembled code, I've for every pair of .h and .c files one assembler file each. Resulting in a total of like 15 but I will upload the ones who might be important in a second. Also I've got the PGA970.out file which im using to load onto my MCU but it seems that it is encrypted.

Comment: @Lundin Seems like my assembler Code is too long. Can I upload the files somewhere?

Comment: You don't need the whole code, just main() with the `__set_PRIMASK(0);` macro. This will either be one of the mentioned instructions, or in case the function call isn't inlined, a function call to a function which you then need to disassemble instead.

Comment: Is the vector table linked and located to the correct address, (probably 0), in a loadable segment?  I don't trust linkers: I explicitly load the vector table in startup code.

Comment: @Lundin 
`.dwpsn file "../source/core/pga970_main.c",line 46,column 4,is_stmt,isa 1
        MOVS      A1, #0;               ; [DPU_V6M0_PIPE] |46| 
        MSR       PRIMASK, A1           ; [DPU_V6M0_PIPE] |46| `
I'm sorry, I'm not able to read assembler yet (never tried). I don't really know whats happening there.

Comment: @MartinJames I found this section in the documentary:
"The vector table.  Note that the proper constructs must be placed on this to ensure that it ends up at physical address 0x0000.0000 or at the start of the program if located at a start address other than 0."
It refers to the last code shown in my original post. I didn't do anything with the vectortable yet since it is located in the startup.c file I thought that this should be enough.

Comment: @Lundin Arm stated that the `CPSIE i` instruction is equivalent to writing a 0 into `PRIMASK`.
The `CPSID i` instruction is equivalent to writing a 1 into `PRIMASK`.
The `CPSIE f` instruction is equivalent to writing a 0 into `FAULTMASK`.
The `CPSID f` instruction is equivalent to writing a 1 into `FAULTMASK`.
Regarding ur previous question I'm using `__set_PRIMASK(0);` which equals `CPSIE i`. For now im also using `__set_FAULTMASK(0);` in order to set `CPSIE f`

Comment: Yeah `CPSIE i` will sets PRIMASK. Anyway it's a very easy thing to test, `__asm("CPSIE i");` or whatever equivalent inline asm syntax your compiler uses. Though maybe your problem isn't at all related to the interrupt not getting called, but something with system clocks? How to configure the clock is very part-specific, but it's usually never trivial on any modern MCU. I'm mostly used to the Microchip ARMs where you have to "route" the system clock to various peripherals or nothing will work... not required for Systick though, at least not on Microchip parts.

Comment: @Lundin The Clock should be properly set up. I used the guides provided by arm and TI for that which were identical for this. I used `SYST_Config(0x0000004F,0x00000007);`to set a reload value and enable the clock + enable the SYST interrupts. I Think that my problem lies within the vector table or its connection since Exception 15 in the vectortable doesnt seem to acvtivate upon setting the flagbit in the CSR.

Comment: @PaulR That part should be somewhat standardized through CMSIS. Looking at an M0+ project for a Microchip part, i set Systick CTRL register to 0x7, where magic number 0x7 equals three bit flags: bitmask 0x1 = enable, bitmask 0x2 = systick interrupt, bitmask 0x4 = clock source internal. If you use an external clock, then you need a different clock source setup.

Comment: However, according to my notes, the LOAD register should be set to desired time between interrupts divided by the time of one CPU tick. In this project I looked at I wanted Systick once every 1ms and the clock was running at 16MHz = 62.5ns. 1ms/62.5ns = 16000 and then I set the LOAD register to 16000-1. Your 0x4F corresponds to 80-1, so the question is what interrupt frequency you want and what speed your clock is running at.

Comment: @Lundin I'm enabling bit 0, 1 and 2 of this register which have the following functions: CLKSOURCE:Selects the SysTick timer clock source: 0 = reference clock 1 = processor clock. TICKIN: Enables SysTick exception request: 0 = counting down to zero does not assert the SysTick exception request.ENABLE: 0 = counter disabled 1 = counter enabled. I'm not using an external clock. 

1 = counting down to zero to asserts the SysTick exception request.

Comment: Yes you're right on the timing but since the purpose of this programm is purely educational at the moment I didn't care about its value. That's why I chose such a low value in order to take less time while using step by step debugging. My clock is running at 8 MHz

Comment: At this point I would create a new blank project in the IDE with nothing but systick in it, run it on the same hardware and take it from there. Or ideally port away from TI since their customer support is non-existent.